# combination of 广 and マ

Tags: kanji

In an anime called ゴクドーくん漫遊記, there is a character called 一休（いっきゅう） who is kind of a devilish imp. He, along with another impish character, bears on his forehead a mark I cannot decipher. It appears to be a combination of 广 and マ.

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps0Ux.jpg)

Can anyone understand this symbol and explain it to me?

Comment: Nonstandard abbreviated kanji are usually not used as tattoo, etc., so this looks comical or childish to me.

Comment: SOLUTION: This is an abbreviated kanji for 魔, which means demon, which is perfect 'cuz he is.

Comment: More examples at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryakuji.